# Can you use logo design that wasn't used by the client in your portfolio?

Tags: logo, portfolio

...or if I just want to showcase my ideas for existing companies with not-so-great logos, can I put that in my portfolio? or even fictitious companies, is that okay to build up on portfolio?

Comment: What does it say in your contract?

Comment: For the future, the easiest way to reassure yourself about this is to add a clause in your contract stating that you have the right to showcase the work in your portfolio. Then the client can spell out what is and isn't okay to show the public before you've even started, and everyone is clear.

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason why not.

The entire world is not so contract-obsessed as the US, so unless you have a massively complicated contract that mentions this (and that to me would be wildly bizarre), go ahead.

You should also be able to put the logos that *are* in use in your portfolio too. That is kinda what a portfolio *is*.

And fictional logos? Absolutely. It is nice to see some stuff that are entirely from your own imagination too.

Comment: I disagree with you "assuming" that the US is so contract-based..  If he has promised or is doing work for an agency and has agreed not to disclose any work to the public that is a reality.  If a project branding is for a new press release and you are telling him sure why not and he has agreed to not release any work per his agreement then your answer is incorrect.  Again, that is why I asked what is in his contract.  If this is simply a logo design with any form of contract or anything in writing then so be it..

Comment: If there was a contract in which these things were stated, there would hardly be point in asking a question.

Comment: yet we do get people that still ask...

Comment: The artist always has the right to show work unless that right was *expressly* given away in a contract. In the US, even for logo design, the artist retains **all rights** until they are signed away specifically.

Comment: I agree, unless is has been explicitly agreed upon to not show the work, then by all means do.

Comment: What if it's designing something on your own for a company that is NOT fictitious? Are we allowed to display their company name and such on the design work?

Comment: It depends on the company, I would think, if they are anal and crazy paranoid. But as long as you make it reasonably clear that this is a _fictional_ logo, that it is an exercise for you, a creative process, I would reckon it is fine. I cannot really imagine that that would be a problem.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for all the answers. I just wanted to make sure.. because it is really an exercise for me, and I feel that it's a good way to be able to showcase my skills while I'm just starting out as a freelance designer. Any other good ideas/exercises/ways to do this?

Comment: Fictional and otherwise identity work can always benefit from making visual mockups for coffemugs, car decals, websites, t-shirts and such.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did couple of successful master classes about portfolio in past and would suggest - use any your work in portfolio that show your skills on the edge. No any excuses for mediocre work - "it is approved by client". It is YOUR portfolio, if you disagree with client, use what you think is best.

Client must sell own services/products. You must sell own.